# HP-UFT 12.02: How to set list of test to run without ALM managing tool

Tags: hp-uft

I have an UFT tool 12.02. A number of test are already created. Now i am trying to run all this test, one after another, without using ALM. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Test Batch Runner](http://www.ufthelp.com/2013/03/test-batch-runner-in-uft.html).